# Motorola flipout cannot access SD card while USB connected

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a Motorola flipout with Android 2.1. and the USB my driver is the following:
http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/USB_Drivers/Handset_USB_Driver_64/

Whenever I connect the USB cord to the cellphone I can access the SD card from the computer and I no longer can access it from the cellphone. That means that any software on the phone that needs to access the SD card can't do so, therefore I can't debug anything that needs file access. Is there any way to connect the USB cord yet at the same time *not* mount the SD card file system onto the computer filesystem?

Comment: Once you connect your phone the notificacion bar should have a "USB connected, select to copy files..." once you click that, make sure the option in there is off.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? Or just in general? In general, you can just pull down the notification shade and click the option to turn off USB storage mode.

Comment: Thanks guys I followed your advice and it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD card can only be mounted by one device at a time.  It sounds like the default setting upon USB connection is to basically mount the SD card to your computer so it can browse/edit the files.  Use blindstuff's method to disable USB storage mode.  your phone will still be connected via USB allowing you to use adb to debug applications.

Answer (score 0):

Blindstuff called it.  The reason you cannot is because the SD card is in use by the computer (depending on how you've connected of course).  While the SD card is in use by the computer, it's not available to the device.

I strongly suspect that's an artifact of SD cards, not Android (or iPhone, or anything else).